# How to find out which server is clashing on 127.0.0.1

Tags: django, server, pycharm

I have just started experiencing a problem where the local server address my PyCharm Django project is running on (127.0.0.1:8000) is clashing with some other server running on my laptop also on 127.0.0.1, so that instead of seeing my Django home page I now see a page that says "It Works!".

I was playing with some software earlier called VirtualHostX which I think has done something to my computer and installed a server that launches automatically. I have removed VirtualHostX and rebooted but I am still getting this clash so unless I change the IP address the Django server runs on it clashes with the other server.

What is the best way to track down what is happening? Is there a file somewhere I can edit to stop this other server running?

Comment: If the port was  clashing django won't run afaik. It seems you have apache installed  and running  somewhere. To test  django  you need ip  with port i.e. 127.0.0.1:8000 on  address bar.

Comment: My Django project was working fine and showing the correct home page but now it shows "It works instead".

Comment: Just change the port your running on in pycharm to see if that really is the problem.

Comment: Ah! That seems to have fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a shell to see which process is listening on port 8000

```
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8000 | grep LISTEN
```

"It works" makes me think of a active apache webserver.

You can try

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

to see if you have an active apache server running.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clashing. "It works" is what Django shows you when you haven't set up any URLs yet. So, set some up.

Comment: My Django project was working fine before and showing the correct home page but now it shows "It works instead". If I change the server address from 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.1.200 it works. That is why I thought maybe there was a clash on 127.0.0.1?